# D3 - Appending Rectangle Stops Tooltip From Working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I plotted a data set with tooltips enabled. However, if I add further elements to the svg, the tooltip part generates an error.
As a concrete example,  I have:

```
var canvas = ....;
canvas.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)
...
...
.append("title")
.text(function(d){return tooltiptext;});
...
canvas.append("rect").attr("x",0).attr("y",0)
.attr("width",w).attr("height",h).style("fill","purple")
.style("fill-opacity",0.1);
```

Adding the last canvas.append(...) makes the tooltip part not work.
How do I fix this?

Here is a working jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kbkbkb/rkok5zmr/

Thank you

Comment: Your question was tagged `canvas`, but you are using `svg`, I've swapped the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last rectangle you append sits on top of everything. This effectively blocks the mouseover events of the elements underneath.

In svg, elements are layered in the order they are appended (newly appended are on top of previously appended), and pointer/mouse events don't see through other elements by default.

To fix this, you can set the pointer-events property of the purple rectangle to none:

```
.style("pointer-events","none")
```

```js
var data = [5, 6, 3, 7, 10];

var w = 300,
  h = 200;

var ys = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 0.9 * h]);
var bw = Math.floor(w / data.length);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", bw * 0.9)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return ys(d);
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return bw * i;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - ys(d);
  })
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });


svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr("width",w)
    .attr("height",h)
    .style("fill","purple")
    .style("fill-opacity",0.1)
    .style("pointer-events","none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This effectively makes the element see through for mouse events.

Alternatively you could set a class or id for the purple rectangle and use css to set pointer-events to none for it:

```js
var data = [5, 6, 3, 7, 10];

var w = 300,
  h = 200;

var ys = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 0.9 * h]);
var bw = Math.floor(w / data.length);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", bw * 0.9)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return ys(d);
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return bw * i;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - ys(d);
  })
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });


svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr("width",w)
    .attr("height",h)
    .style("fill","purple")
    .style("fill-opacity",0.1)
    .attr("class","overlay")
```

```css
.overlay{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Lastly, as a different approach, you could append the purple rectangle first, so that the bars of the chart are ontop of it, and there is no need to change the pointer-events setting. *Note that this method requires a change to your enter selection for the bar chart - selectAll("rect") will include the purple rectangle, so you could change this to `selectAll(null)`, as I did in my example.*

```js
var data = [5, 6, 3, 7, 10];

var w = 300,
  h = 200;

var ys = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 0.9 * h]);
var bw = Math.floor(w / data.length);

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);


svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr("width",w)
    .attr("height",h)
    .style("fill","purple")
    .style("fill-opacity",0.1)

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", bw * 0.9)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return ys(d);
  })
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return bw * i;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - ys(d);
  })
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

*I've changed your variable name `canvas` to `svg` in my answer as canvas can be misleading, since d3 visualizations often use canvas as opposed to svg and both involve different methods of implementation*